# Using kdiff3 to Edit Files During Diffs/Comparisons with TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, kdiff3

Often when I do a file comparison, I want to edit my local file before committing to TFS (it's efficient). I'm able to do this with kdiff3's 3-way *merge*.  But how do I accomplish this during *comparison*?  I know that it's possible with BeyondCompare3, as I used to do it in the past.

These are my **Tools** --> **Options** --> **Visual Studio Team Foundation Server** --> **Configure User Tools** --> **Compare Operation**:

```
%1 -fname %6 %2 -fname %7
```

Comment: This is easy to do with TortoiseMerge, which I believe is the default diff tool for TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 3):

Was looking for answer myself, found this question, so updating with my findings.

Appears to me that edit of A or B file isn't supported out of the box in kdiff3, but you can keep an eye on [this feature request](http://sourceforge.net/p/kdiff3/feature-requests/9/) opened in 2004 :)

There are workarounds though (found in comments [here](http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2010/01/31/replace-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-team-system-with-winmerge/))

**Option 1** is to use these parameters for Compare: `%1 --fname %6 %2 --fname %7 -o %2`, it will output to B (`-o %2` part).

**Option 2** is to use parameters you're using but then you'll need to click "Merge current file" in Menu and after that click "Select Line(s) from B" in the output window context menu, after that you'll be able to edit.

Comment: Thank you for this workaround found in the comments of the Paul Bouwer site.  And dang the feature request was from 2004 to implement the enhancement in KDiff3!   The good news is I now know that WinMerge is capable of this.